# HOW TO embedd traffic information in a Custom MapView

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkmapview

I am currently able to get my location pinned down on the MapView using the MAPKIT.
I wanted to get the traffic info embedded on the same MapView around the same location.
I have attached a sample screenshot of the desired view. 
Could anyone please let me know what Api or how I need to go about getting this done.

Here is the image of the desired output:
[image]
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your current location access Google Api

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=latitude,longitude&output=xml

This will return details about the surrounding areas and thier descriptions. You can parse those values and can use it in your map.

You can also get output in json, csv formats also.

Want to know about Google Map Web services [Click Here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html)